# Running 'Docker' run during within build of Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, qemu

I am able to use **dind**, and **run/build** containers inside running container using:

```
docker run -it --privileged -v /var/run/docker.sh:/var/run/docker.sh -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

But I want to install **arm64 emulator** using ready image:

```
docker run --privileged --rm tonistiigi/binfmt --install arm64
```

I achieved needed functionalities by running **dind** container, configuring and docker commit, but if it is possible to do it within build it will be much better.

So is there something like this below but for build time?

```
docker run -it --privileged -v /var/run/docker.sh:/var/run/docker.sh -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: In general you can't do anything inside a Dockerfile that causes side effects outside the image build; if you were able to start an additional container on the host, it wouldn't be persisted in the image.

Comment: @DavidMaze but if i run container and use tonistiigi/binfmt inside, commit, i am able to use qemu functionality later everywhere where i pull such image